# Does theme update also update a child theme zip

Tags: wordpress-theming, updates, wordpress

total wordpress beginner here. I purchased a organicfood theme and when I got an updated version for it, among other files I also found organicfood child theme zip in main directory.

I know that organicfood.zip contains the updated version of parent theme but I don't know if same goes for organicfood child theme zip. Is the child zip added with every update just so that a new buyer has that default child theme template?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have idea of parent and child theme ? As per i knowledge wherever we use parent and child theme only update parent theme only and if we need any changes like manually we can change on child theme and when we update theme that change not overwrite its benefit of parent and child theme.